# Is both NULL and false are equivalent to 0 (the int value)?

Tags: c, null, boolean

Is both NULL and false are equivalent to 0 (int) in C ?
For example both lines below return the same value?

```
return NULL;

return false;
```

Comment: When `NULL` and `false` are compared with a literal `0`, they will compare equal. But the types of `NULL`, `false` and `0` are different. So operations other than a comparison may result in warnings about type mismatches.

Comment: Because the value of false is int whereas NULL is actually a pointer so it just contain an adress?

Comment: It gets confusing because the types have a long and convoluted history. Even today, the types depend on the implementation. By convention, `NULL` is a pointer (typically a pointer to void), `false` is a boolean (which has a whole convoluted history unto itself), and `0` is an `int` (unless otherwise specified using a suffix, e.g. `0ULL`). In short, the whole thing is just a big mess.